# Hex editor for open large binary file

Tags: c#, hex-editors

I want to create a hex editor to open large binary files.
This is my code. It works well for small files. But when I open large files, Hex editor faces problem.

```
data[] ... array of byte

string str = "";
byte[] temp = null;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (data.Length - 16); i += 16)
{
    temp = _sub_array(data, i, 16);
    str += BitConverter.ToString(temp).Replace("-", "\t");
    str += "\n";
}

temp = _sub_array(data, i, (data.Length - i));
str += BitConverter.ToString(temp).Replace("-", "\t");

richTextBox.Text = str;
```

Comment: Don't load the whole file to memory. Load necessary parts when needed.

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder rather than a string.

Comment: *"Hex editor faces problem"* => problem is solved with *solution*.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in the comments, you should try to avoid reading in the entire file at once.  However, if you need the entire file in memory at once, I think your main problem might be the "stickiness" that the program will experience while reading and converting data.  You are wiser to use a separate thread for the hex work and let the main thread focus on keeping your UI operating smoothly.  You could also use tasks instead of threads, either way.  So using your code snippet, make it look more like this:

```
data[] ... array of byte

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(readHexFile);
    t.Start();
}

private void readHexFile()
{
    string str = "";
    byte[] temp = null;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (data.Length - 16); i += 16)
    {
        temp = _sub_array(data, i, 16);
        str += BitConverter.ToString(temp).Replace("-", "\t");
        str += "\n";
    }

    temp = _sub_array(data, i, (data.Length - i));
    str += BitConverter.ToString(temp).Replace("-", "\t");

    BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> richTextBox.Text = str));
}
```

You'll need to add "using System.Threading" to get access to threads.  Also note the BeginInvoke with the richTextBox.Text work in a lambda expression.  This is necessary when you run the data processing on a separate thread because if you try to access the textbox directly with that thread, Windows will complain about a cross-thread call.  Only the thread that made the control is allowed to access it directly.  BeginInvoke doesn't access the control directly, so you can use it from the data processing thread to get text written to the control.  This will stop the data processing from "gumming up" the UI responsiveness.

This may seem intimidating at first if you have never done it, but trust me.  If you get the hang of Threads and Tasks (which are different inside the machine but can be manipulated by similar developer tools) you will never want to render to the UI from the main thread again.

EDIT: I left the string from your code as it was, but I agree with the comment suggesting StringBuilder instead.  Strings are immutable, so each time you concatenate to the string, internally what's happening is that the whole string is being scrapped and a new one is being made with the additional text.  So yeah, do switch to a StringBuilder object as well.

Answer (score 1):

So you've got working code for small files, but you face problems with large files.  You don't mention what those problems are so here are a few guesses:

- If you're loading the entire file into a `byte[]`, then you could have a memory issue and possibly throw an `OutOfMemoryException`
- You're concatenating a `string` repeatedly.  This is not only a memory issue, but a performance one too (Reference Jon Skeet's article http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)
- You're `_sub_array()` is called repeatedly and returns a 16 length `byte[]`, yet another memory and performance issue.
- You call `String.Replace()` repeatedly (See bullet 2).

I consider these to be memory problems because we don't know when the Garbage Collector will clean up the memory.

So let's address these potential problems:

- Read your file 16 bytes at a time (@EZI comment), this also eliminates the need for your `_sub_array()`.  Look into the [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) class to read 16 bytes at a time.
- `BitConverter.ToString()` these 16 bytes into a `StringBuilder` with `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` (My comment), but don't do the `String.Replace()` until you're done reading the file.
- Once you're done reading the file, you can assign the `StringBuilder` to your `RichTextBox` like so (sb is a variable name used for `StringBuilder`): `richTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();`

Hope this helps...